# In which package is `R.string.cast_casting_to_device`

Tags: android, casting, android-resources

I can't find the full package name of `R.string.cast_casting_to_device` for example
`com.google.android.something.R.string.cast_casting_to_device`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.R` from
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework`

Comment: just posted the correct answer if you can update your answer to that I'll accept yours thank you

Comment: @Arlind Updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its inside `com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.R` which is part of the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:` android library.

I'd like to thank me, myself and I